# Presto/SQL find next value that meets a condition

Tags: sql, window-functions, lag, presto

I have a table looks like below, first 3 columns are in the original table and last 2 columns are what I want. So what I want are:

1. find if within the next 30 days of a record if an event of "issued" happens
2. if "issued" happens, what's the stamp of the "issued"

I was able to find if issued happened by replacing "issued" in the original table with 1 and used a self join and sum the "replaced issued" by `sum(case when t2.event_ts between t1.event_ts and date_add('day',30,t1.event_ts) then t2.issued end) as issued_in_month`.

But I'm not sure how to get the "issued" timestamp.

How can I do this in Presto?
Thanks

```
| event_id                         | event_ts      | event_name | issued_within_30_days | issued_ts     |
|----------------------------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|---------------|
| fc25df28c8bb188e8d15c1fea4acd06a | 6/1/18 21:31  | CLICK      | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| 2b48d5ea80829cdd1014a68631160eb0 | 6/6/18 17:25  | OPEN       | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| f4f6d9af7217031e5579c6d741fe3d21 | 6/8/18 0:00   | MAIL_DROP  | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| 4a5af238e28688bf899def0905210550 | 6/10/18 4:25  | OPEN       | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| a7945e7087c27d7f6bd7c66a397bf6bf | 6/25/18 17:53 | CLICK      | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| 82eba7f62a9398347d67073291547765 | 6/27/18 4:58  | OPEN       | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| 6d6984822e98009a0a30deda1204a5e0 | 6/27/18 4:58  | CLICK      | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| 6229316a4ebcb56124e1180c9e2f60be | 6/27/18 10:18 | ISSUED     | 1                     | 6/27/18 10:18 |
| 3994ed57abc330e16965f13a2a37edd8 | 6/27/18 11:19 | SEND       | 0                     |               |
| 70f0a4d73975f26523415625309f1f64 | 7/4/18 17:30  | SEND       | 0                     |               |
| a7dd44648a0ce0029ad1ec7106fcf95c | 7/4/18 18:37  | OPEN       | 0                     |               |
| 8a823394754276a46fa3021ddc7a7290 | 7/6/18 0:00   | MAIL_DROP  | 0                     |               |
| 7a4c451554ba08da59a85a3fa61de7b6 | 7/6/18 20:18  | SEND       | 0                     |               |
| f992b7a5a25f765e5fd6f7dde129f9dc | 7/7/18 1:16   | OPEN       | 0                     |               |
| 9370e4901a4796371827e2f45862ba66 | 7/11/18 4:35  | CLICK      | 0                     |               |
| 96badd7253344f79c7ac2a47032d5942 | 2/22/19 17:20 | ISSUED     | 0                     |               |
```

Comment: Is "stamp" supposed to mean `event_ts`?  Please show the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes. the results i want are in the last two columns of the table above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method might be a cumulative min and some `case` expressions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when next_issued_ts < event_ts + interval '30' day
             then 1 else 0
        end) as issued_within_30_days,
       (case when next_issued_ts < event_ts + interval '30' day
             then next_issued_ts
        end) as issued_ts
from (select t.*,
             min(case when event = 'issued' then event_ts end) over
                 (order by event_ts desc) as next_issued_ts
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: It's not working as the "next_issued_ts" is only showing the event_ts of the first "issued".

Comment: @AngieLi . . . That `order by` should be `desc`.  I just fixed the answer.